# Combining two character buffers in C

Tags: c

I am trying to combine two character buffers in C but I am losing bytes at the end.  My current code is as below:

```
//firstblock and secondblock are captured at different times from the passed in character buffer variable named buf
firstblock = (char*) malloc(512*sizeof(char));
memcpy(firstblock, buf, 512);
secondblock = (char*) malloc(512*sizeof(char));
memcpy(secondblock,  buf, 512);

//minimum code to test combining:
logMessage(LOG_INFO_LEVEL, "first block captured as [%s]", firstblock);
logMessage(LOG_INFO_LEVEL, "second block captured as [%s]", secondblock);
char *combinedblock;
combinedblock = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(1024));
memcpy(combinedblock, firstblock, 512);
//logMessage(LOG_INFO_LEVEL, "combined block with just the first part [%s]", combinedblock);
memcpy(combinedblock+512, secondblock, 512);
logMessage(LOG_INFO_LEVEL, "combined block with the second block added [%s]", combinedblock);
```

My output is as below:

first block captured as [4ohizB}/ 6,7:}0,H@FbACm.bL~%=a>x!<v|Qrv6pFhGSrVMzv}z;Z+nfy47toXdOE;C@% ejPcB=ukbwE9*d+nBs.+a4qt^cSWK!D+N@=<Hkv7tLPX1L]|1!HawzKEc-$gQeq4tp6bz<]JSbF_j9/-43e9eRRH+Zk3cpLr4|ZD^^L.&JT$l4nD6>rmlzG%l_H6)qWq[S**puDt2l CmRkr7F^B:!Z5oEXy_{~vV-7N8E-6SA&rCT 1(DbeQhTzJw,8Cp,]@N_T,%}LH7[rDg#)xhc@^ekYI-zsq|m4HFvbq0wJZ8^z{w+B|{bSh3~ugc%:QFt4VP0bV8O8dyQ=EB1=6MvJ;_Hbqr;IJ&7[oMhYS;xYpF>Vh%74&.lOr*^!##I@Mg/:At*fJ@VW0Mgo}YLSfBJk+4p6<rW2rGy!x{JUin!vKzF8&>CUzGQp;vaFPu[~fo*s@>@hDJ5-^meWpu/8fVpctX{3Nqn[, |c]T3rN-)kpJkYG.gze[C@|kQRL]

second block captured as [bOv>AHp=|<_;c]73Dud+(1o#FJr~ZB1;2NgI;]}oAcIoqK(;8Pd,0.r6CUQ7xp~+nEELqkZ|9-$vkZ%~k#2N&2LWnA~GZdH][$-:3vytS88Opd8==JG&Db29IqEB8EO*pyPJIt?L-e1Vk1|A=kN)*+jLAytyekc$ C[|-rP$F8gr}4.&enyg0{@lkG8&~FY|16c(FT)52j|teYT3-*og4G?N{JX?tP6|@|oZlGD9LvAH=kA=9d8>vS?9/yzy(tLZYf]9>QA/E|^k,Q#iYE_SIY7&vz^(-h_phap.$L*ad1j[fi2<qqr$a[0hB9f&LI&5XTm$l-S$9?fsdN$UQEa~!Gs>a/3@4#bCP5zU]1Hlr.GT9].)|]9[ht2U{NJ1y0,FTteR*QuWmfMH ?YwEgOOP073oE)TCRq;>d;#gJ:ju)eoz-ZB[TFHN8;&/B|CAIkTsj4twx:A?S,OIeMt6R$ZE*z7STP8X{6-[@{!6P=&En+|t5Ww ^Zfq~b&tlk_N]]

combined block with the second block added [4ohizB}/ 6,7:}0,H@FbACm.bL~%=a>x!<v|Qrv6pFhGSrVMzv}z;Z+nfy47toXdOE;C@% ejPcB=ukbwE9*d+nBs.+a4qt^cSWK!D+N@=<Hkv7tLPX1L]|1!HawzKEc-$gQeq4tp6bz<]JSbF_j9/-43e9eRRH+Zk3cpLr4|ZD^^L.&JT$l4nD6>rmlzG%l_H6)qWq[S**puDt2l CmRkr7F^B:!Z5oEXy_{~vV-7N8E-6SA&rCT 1(DbeQhTzJw,8Cp,]@N_T,%}LH7[rDg#)xhc@^ekYI-zsq|m4HFvbq0wJZ8^z{w+B|{bSh3~ugc%:QFt4VP0bV8O8dyQ=EB1=6MvJ;_Hbqr;IJ&7[oMhYS;xYpF>Vh%74&.lOr*^!##I@Mg/:At*fJ@VW0Mgo}YLSfBJk+4p6<rW2rGy!x{JUin!vKzF8&>CUzGQp;vaFPu[~fo*s@>@hDJ5-^meWpu/8fVpctX{3Nqn[, |c]T3rN-)kpJkYG.gze[C@|kQRLbOv>AHp=|<_;c]73Dud+(1o#FJr~ZB1;2NgI;]}oAcIoqK(;8Pd,0.r6CUQ7xp~+nEELqkZ|9-$vkZ%~k#2N&2LWnA~GZdH][$-:3vytS88Opd8==JG&Db29IqEB8EO*pyPJIt?L-e1Vk1|A=kN)*+jLAytyekc$ C[|-rP$F8gr}4.&enyg0{@lkG8&~FY|16c(FT)52j|teYT3-*og4G?N{JX?tP6|@|oZlGD9LvAH=kA=9d8>vS?9/yzy(tLZYf]9>QA/E|^k,Q#iYE_SIY7&vz^(-h_phap.$L*ad1j[fi2<qqr$a[0hB9f&LI&5XTm$l-S$9?fsdN$UQEa~!Gs>a/3@4#bCP5zU]1Hlr.GT9].)|]9[ht2U{NJ1y0,FTteR*QuWmfMH ?YwEgOOP073oE)TCRq;>d;#gJ:ju)eoz-ZB[TFHN8;&/B|CAIkTsj4<twx:A?S,OIeMt6R

As you can see the combined block is missing the bytes/characters $ZE*z7STP8X{6-[@{!6>P=&En+|t5Ww ^Zfq~b&tlk_N which is the last 53 bytes of the second block.

Please review and confirm what I could be doing wrong in combining the two blocks and showing the contents of the combined block.

Comment: Are you sure there's no limit on the `logMessage()` output? Try it with less extra stuff in the format string and see if the output differs by that amount of characters.

Comment: Doesn't `logMessage` require data for `%s` null-terminated?

Comment: If you stick a null character at the end of the combined block, and do a strlen(), what does it say? And what does it print if you use something else than logMessage()? May have to malloc() a byte more for this, btw.

Comment: How do I add a null character at the end of the combinedblock?

Comment: btw `sizeof (char)` is 1 because `sizeof` returns the size of the thing **in characters**.